# How to analysis protobuf with AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, protocol-buffers

We use protobuf to transmit data, and I try to send a network request using AFNetworking. I can request success, but I can't resolve the datagram error

**com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<0a060a04 68747470 1a050a03 303030>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: application/x-protobuf}**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFNetworking's AFURLResponseSerializer will not allow any content type not present in its acceptableContentTypes set. In order to be able to process this data, you should provide your own response serializer and set it as your AFURLSessionManager's responseSerializer property.

Comment: 对不起有点晚了，我现在才明白怎么确定对的答案... :)